# Svg animation having jerk in mobile safari

Tags: html, css, svg

I created an svg animation through online tool. I have tried it in multiple ways but not getting the proper solution.

Here is my svg code. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```css
body {
    background: #000;
}

@-webkit-keyframes SkLgXTFYahz_HJRA_JEpG_Animation {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    6.67% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-8deg);
        transform: rotate(-8deg);
    }
    13.33% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}

@keyframes SkLgXTFYahz_HJRA_JEpG_Animation {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    6.67% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-8deg);
        transform: rotate(-8deg);
    }
    13.33% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes SkLgXTFYahz_Hyy3OyEaM_Animation {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    13.33% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    20% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    26.67% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    }
    33.33% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    40% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    46.67% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    }
    53.33% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    66.67% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    }
    73.33% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
}

@keyframes SkLgXTFYahz_Hyy3OyEaM_Animation {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    13.33% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    20% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    26.67% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    }
    33.33% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    40% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    46.67% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    }
    53.33% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    66.67% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    }
    73.33% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes SkLgXTFYahz_r1RiuJVaG_Animation {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
    6.67% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -100px);
        transform: translate(0px, -100px);
    }
    13.33% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
    20% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
    26.67% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-67px, 0px);
        transform: translate(-67px, 0px);
    }
    33.33% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-134px, 0px);
        transform: translate(-134px, 0px);
    }
    40% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-134px, 0px);
        transform: translate(-134px, 0px);
    }
    46.67% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
    53.33% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(134px, 0px);
        transform: translate(134px, 0px);
    }
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(134px, 0px);
        transform: translate(134px, 0px);
    }
    66.67% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(67px, 0px);
        transform: translate(67px, 0px);
    }
    73.33% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
}

@keyframes SkLgXTFYahz_r1RiuJVaG_Animation {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
    6.67% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -100px);
        transform: translate(0px, -100px);
    }
    13.33% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
    20% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
    26.67% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-67px, 0px);
        transform: translate(-67px, 0px);
    }
    33.33% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-134px, 0px);
        transform: translate(-134px, 0px);
    }
    40% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-134px, 0px);
        transform: translate(-134px, 0px);
    }
    46.67% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
    53.33% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(134px, 0px);
        transform: translate(134px, 0px);
    }
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(134px, 0px);
        transform: translate(134px, 0px);
    }
    66.67% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(67px, 0px);
        transform: translate(67px, 0px);
    }
    73.33% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rkXxQTYYTnG_Animation {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    13.33% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    93.33% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes rkXxQTYYTnG_Animation {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    13.33% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    93.33% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rkOXaYYa3M_BJVcuJNTf_Animation {
    40% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    46.67% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.9, 0.9);
        transform: scale(0.9, 0.9);
    }
    53.33% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    86.67% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    }
    93.33% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
}

@keyframes rkOXaYYa3M_BJVcuJNTf_Animation {
    40% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    46.67% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.9, 0.9);
        transform: scale(0.9, 0.9);
    }
    53.33% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    86.67% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    }
    93.33% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rkOXaYYa3M_rJf9u1Eaf_Animation {
    40% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
    46.67% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-134px, 0px);
        transform: translate(-134px, 0px);
    }
    53.33% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-268px, 0px);
        transform: translate(-268px, 0px);
    }
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-268px, 0px);
        transform: translate(-268px, 0px);
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-268px, 0px);
        transform: translate(-268px, 0px);
    }
    86.67% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-134px, 0px);
        transform: translate(-134px, 0px);
    }
    93.33% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
}

@keyframes rkOXaYYa3M_rJf9u1Eaf_Animation {
    40% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
    46.67% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-134px, 0px);
        transform: translate(-134px, 0px);
    }
    53.33% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-268px, 0px);
        transform: translate(-268px, 0px);
    }
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-268px, 0px);
        transform: translate(-268px, 0px);
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-268px, 0px);
        transform: translate(-268px, 0px);
    }
    86.67% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-134px, 0px);
        transform: translate(-134px, 0px);
    }
    93.33% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rJxXatK6hf_SkoFu1Epf_Animation {
    20% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    26.67% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.9, 0.9);
        transform: scale(0.9, 0.9);
    }
    33.33% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    40% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    66.67% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.9, 0.9);
        transform: scale(0.9, 0.9);
    }
    73.33% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    86.67% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.9, 0.9);
        transform: scale(0.9, 0.9);
    }
    93.33% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
}

@keyframes rJxXatK6hf_SkoFu1Epf_Animation {
    20% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    26.67% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.9, 0.9);
        transform: scale(0.9, 0.9);
    }
    33.33% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    40% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    66.67% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.9, 0.9);
        transform: scale(0.9, 0.9);
    }
    73.33% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    86.67% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.9, 0.9);
        transform: scale(0.9, 0.9);
    }
    93.33% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rJxXatK6hf_rJOt_14pz_Animation {
    20% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
    26.67% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(67px, 0px);
        transform: translate(67px, 0px);
    }
    33.33% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(134px, 0px);
        transform: translate(134px, 0px);
    }
    40% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(134px, 0px);
        transform: translate(134px, 0px);
    }
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(134px, 0px);
        transform: translate(134px, 0px);
    }
    66.67% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(201px, 0px);
        transform: translate(201px, 0px);
    }
    73.33% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(268px, 0px);
        transform: translate(268px, 0px);
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(268px, 0px);
        transform: translate(268px, 0px);
    }
    86.67% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(134px, 0px);
        transform: translate(134px, 0px);
    }
    93.33% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
}

@keyframes rJxXatK6hf_rJOt_14pz_Animation {
    20% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
    26.67% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(67px, 0px);
        transform: translate(67px, 0px);
    }
    33.33% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(134px, 0px);
        transform: translate(134px, 0px);
    }
    40% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(134px, 0px);
        transform: translate(134px, 0px);
    }
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(134px, 0px);
        transform: translate(134px, 0px);
    }
    66.67% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(201px, 0px);
        transform: translate(201px, 0px);
    }
    73.33% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(268px, 0px);
        transform: translate(268px, 0px);
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(268px, 0px);
        transform: translate(268px, 0px);
    }
    86.67% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(134px, 0px);
        transform: translate(134px, 0px);
    }
    93.33% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
}

#B1XatYT3G * {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 7.5s;
    animation-duration: 7.5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
}

#HJrmaFt6hz {
    fill: #9F2659;
}

#ryPQTtYahz {
    fill: #FFFFFF;
}

#By67ptFThM {
    fill: #9F2659;
}

#By1eXpKKThG {
    fill: #FFFFFF;
}

#SkxxmTtYanM {
    fill: #FFFFFF;
}

#HJWl7TtKphf {
    fill: #FFFFFF;
}

#HkGgmaKFp3z {
    fill: #FFFFFF;
}

#HkBeQpYF6nf {
    fill: #FFFFFF;
}

#HJqlmaFF63z {
    fill: #9F2659;
}

#S1oe7TtK6hM {
    fill: #FFFFFF;
}

#rJxXatK6hf_rJOt_14pz {
    -webkit-animation-name: rJxXatK6hf_rJOt_14pz_Animation;
    animation-name: rJxXatK6hf_rJOt_14pz_Animation;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-box: fill-box;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}

#rJxXatK6hf_SkoFu1Epf {
    -webkit-animation-name: rJxXatK6hf_SkoFu1Epf_Animation;
    animation-name: rJxXatK6hf_SkoFu1Epf_Animation;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-box: fill-box;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    transform: scale(1, 1);
}

#rkOXaYYa3M_rJf9u1Eaf {
    -webkit-animation-name: rkOXaYYa3M_rJf9u1Eaf_Animation;
    animation-name: rkOXaYYa3M_rJf9u1Eaf_Animation;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-box: fill-box;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}

#rkOXaYYa3M_BJVcuJNTf {
    -webkit-animation-name: rkOXaYYa3M_BJVcuJNTf_Animation;
    animation-name: rkOXaYYa3M_BJVcuJNTf_Animation;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-box: fill-box;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    transform: scale(1, 1);
}

#rkXxQTYYTnG {
    -webkit-animation-name: rkXxQTYYTnG_Animation;
    animation-name: rkXxQTYYTnG_Animation;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-box: fill-box;
    opacity: 1;
}

#SkLgXTFYahz_r1RiuJVaG {
    -webkit-animation-name: SkLgXTFYahz_r1RiuJVaG_Animation;
    animation-name: SkLgXTFYahz_r1RiuJVaG_Animation;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-box: fill-box;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}

#SkLgXTFYahz_Hyy3OyEaM {
    -webkit-animation-name: SkLgXTFYahz_Hyy3OyEaM_Animation;
    animation-name: SkLgXTFYahz_Hyy3OyEaM_Animation;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-box: fill-box;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    transform: scale(1, 1);
}

#SkLgXTFYahz_HJRA_JEpG {
    -webkit-animation-name: SkLgXTFYahz_HJRA_JEpG_Animation;
    animation-name: SkLgXTFYahz_HJRA_JEpG_Animation;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-box: fill-box;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<svg version="1.1" id="B1XatYT3G" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 503 401" enable-background="new 0 0 503 401" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="rJxXatK6hf_rJOt_14pz" data-animator-group="true" data-animator-type="0"><g id="rJxXatK6hf_SkoFu1Epf" data-animator-group="true" data-animator-type="2"><g id="rJxXatK6hf">
 <g id="SybXptYTnG">
  <g id="HyGQ6YF6nf">
   <g id="HkXXaFKT3G">
    <g id="SkEQaYFanf">
     <path d="M110.502,168.5c-29.547,0-53.5,23.953-53.5,53.5s23.953,53.5,53.5,53.5s53.5-23.953,53.5-53.5&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;C164.002,192.447,140.049,168.5,110.502,168.5z" id="HJrmaFt6hz"/>
    </g>
   </g>
  </g>
  <g id="HyI7pFY6nM">
   <path d="M110.502,164.5c-31.756,0-57.5,25.744-57.5,57.5s25.744,57.5,57.5,57.5s57.5-25.744,57.5-57.5&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;C168.002,190.237,142.258,164.5,110.502,164.5z M125.364,221.992L115.94,222l-0.007,34.499h-12.93V222h-8.626v-11.889&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;l8.626-0.008l-0.013-7c0-9.702,2.633-15.603,14.05-15.603h9.518v11.894h-5.951c-4.45,0-4.667,1.661-4.667,4.758l-0.014,5.951&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;h10.699L125.364,221.992z" id="ryPQTtYahz"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</g></g></g>
<g id="rkOXaYYa3M_rJf9u1Eaf" data-animator-group="true" data-animator-type="0"><g id="rkOXaYYa3M_BJVcuJNTf" data-animator-group="true" data-animator-type="2"><g id="rkOXaYYa3M">
 <g id="rkYX6ttanz">
  <g id="ry976tYTnz">
   <g id="SJoXpKYThG">
    <g id="B13Q6FK6nz">
     <path d="M380.5,167.75c-29.914,0-54.25,24.339-54.25,54.25c0,29.909,24.336,54.25,54.25,54.25&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;c29.912,0,54.25-24.341,54.25-54.25C434.75,192.089,410.417,167.75,380.5,167.75z" id="By67ptFThM"/>
    </g>
   </g>
  </g>
  <g id="ry07aFFanG">
   <path d="M380.498,233.512c6.344,0,11.516-5.162,11.516-11.512c0-2.505-0.821-4.818-2.178-6.71&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;c-2.091-2.899-5.493-4.802-9.332-4.802c-3.842,0-7.239,1.9-9.335,4.8c-1.361,1.89-2.176,4.204-2.179,6.709&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;C368.984,228.346,374.152,233.512,380.498,233.512z" id="By1eXpKKThG"/>
   <polygon points="405.636,207.918 405.636,198.271 405.636,196.833 404.192,196.838 394.547,196.868 &#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;394.584,207.954 &#9;&#9;&#9;" id="SkxxmTtYanM"/>
   <path d="M380.5,164.5c-31.706,0-57.5,25.797-57.5,57.5c0,31.701,25.794,57.5,57.5,57.5&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;c31.704,0,57.5-25.799,57.5-57.5C438,190.297,412.209,164.5,380.5,164.5z M413.2,215.29v26.774c0,6.973-5.67,12.642-12.64,12.642&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;h-40.121c-6.972,0-12.64-5.669-12.64-12.642V215.29v-13.35c0-6.972,5.668-12.64,12.64-12.64h40.119&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;c6.972,0,12.642,5.667,12.642,12.64V215.29z" id="HJWl7TtKphf"/>
   <path d="M398.389,222c0,9.858-8.023,17.887-17.889,17.887s-17.886-8.028-17.886-17.887&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;c0-2.373,0.474-4.638,1.316-6.71h-9.763v26.774c0,3.459,2.809,6.263,6.268,6.263h40.121c3.454,0,6.27-2.804,6.27-6.263V215.29&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;h-9.768C397.908,217.362,398.389,219.627,398.389,222z" id="HkGgmaKFp3z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</g></g></g>
<g display="none" id="rkXxQTYYTnG">
 <g display="inline" id="ry4x7TKKTnz">
  <path d="M245.5,269c-2.757,0-5,2.243-5,5s2.243,5,5,5s5-2.243,5-5S248.257,269,245.5,269z" id="HkBeQpYF6nf"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g id="SkLgXTFYahz_r1RiuJVaG" data-animator-group="true" data-animator-type="0"><g id="SkLgXTFYahz_HJRA_JEpG" data-animator-group="true" data-animator-type="1"><g id="SkLgXTFYahz_Hyy3OyEaM" data-animator-group="true" data-animator-type="2"><g id="SkLgXTFYahz">
 <g id="HywlXatK6hf">
  <g id="SkugmptYpnz">
   <g id="Bytx76tK62f">
    <path d="M245.5,168c-29.776,0-54,24.224-54,54c0,29.774,24.224,54,54,54c29.771,0,54-24.226,54-54&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;C299.5,192.224,275.276,168,245.5,168z" id="HJqlmaFF63z"/>
   </g>
  </g>
  <path d="M245.5,164.5c-31.706,0-57.5,25.794-57.5,57.5c0,31.704,25.794,57.5,57.5,57.5&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;c31.701,0,57.5-25.796,57.5-57.5C303,190.294,277.206,164.5,245.5,164.5z M271.149,208.841c0.028,0.569,0.042,1.143,0.042,1.717&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;c0,17.49-13.311,37.649-37.659,37.649c-7.474,0-14.432-2.184-20.286-5.94c1.034,0.122,2.088,0.185,3.156,0.185&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;c6.201,0,11.907-2.115,16.439-5.666c-5.793-0.106-10.682-3.934-12.366-9.19c0.808,0.151,1.64,0.237,2.489,0.237&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;c1.206,0,2.378-0.158,3.488-0.46c-6.054-1.215-10.614-6.562-10.614-12.977c0-0.056,0-0.114,0.002-0.167&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;c1.784,0.987,3.823,1.585,5.99,1.652c-3.547-2.37-5.883-6.422-5.883-11.013c0-2.426,0.649-4.702,1.79-6.658&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;c6.525,8.011,16.281,13.278,27.275,13.834c-0.228-0.973-0.341-1.98-0.341-3.019c0-7.307,5.926-13.235,13.23-13.235&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;c3.809,0,7.246,1.607,9.66,4.179c3.02-0.593,5.85-1.69,8.409-3.214c-0.997,3.095-3.085,5.686-5.828,7.325&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;c2.681-0.32,5.238-1.028,7.604-2.082C275.98,204.647,273.735,206.981,271.149,208.841z" id="S1oe7TtK6hM"/>
 </g>
</g></g></g></g>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've reformatted the CSS code to make it readable. What online tool, what do you expect to happen, what happens instead?

Comment: @ccprog thanks for your help really appreciable, thing actually happens that when loaded it started jerking for iphone and ipad. Here is the URL that i am working on. `http://osumstudio.com/smm` actually its a screen loader